# copy files with folders

Tags: scp, tar, copy, mkdir

The following scp is working as expected.

```
scp /home/admin/* root@ec2-50-112-212-73:/
```

But I need a command that will create the required folder structure on destination server if it does not already exist.

Update:

I can do it in 2 steps as shown below. I will like to know if there is any other way.

```
ssh root@ec2-50-112-212-73  " mkdir -p /home/admin/ "
scp  -r /home/admin/* root@ec2-50-112-212-73:/home/admin/
```

Comment: Do you mean `scp -r`?

Comment: No. equivalent to mkdir -p /home/admin/ on remote server, that will work with scp or tar

Comment: That's what `-r` for: `Recursively copy entire directories. Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using `rsync`:

```
rsync -av -R -f"+ */" -f"- *" /home/admin/* root@ec2-50-112-212-73:/
```

This will only create the directories on the other (ec2) side

Comment: Wouldn't you also need the `-R` option in order to create `/home/admin/`?

Comment: Ah, yes, thought he didn't want that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`scp  -r /home/admin/ root@ec2-50-112-212-73:/home/admin/` will work, assuming you don't specifically want to copy just the non-dotfiles in `/home/admin`.